# Golang request body keep giving EOF error

Tags: json, go, request

I have the following Go program which I want to read the JSON values send from via post. I have tried few different methods example `r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, 1048576)` first then only run `Json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&u)`. All methods seems to be giving the same EOF error. I have even tried this `body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)`. So all seem the same

```
func insertUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  type User struct {        
    Uemail string `json:"uEmail"`
    Upass string `json:"uPass"`    
  }
  var u User
  if r.Method == "POST" {
    if r.Header.Get("Content-Type") != "" {
      value, _ := header.ParseValueAndParams(r.Header, "Content-Type")
      if value != "application/json" {
          msg := "Content-Type header is not application/json"
          json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Errormessage{msg});
          return
      }
    }
    //r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, 1048576)
    /*body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }*/
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&u)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("Decoding error is :", err)
      json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Errormessage{"Message decoding Issue"});
        return
    }
    var uEmail string = u.Uemail
    var uPass string = u.Upass
   
    fmt.Println("User Namess :", uEmail)
    fmt.Println("User Password :", uPass)

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
  }
```

Comment: I am just sending the request via postman I can confirm it send not empty

Comment: I dont understand in my code I dont ready before this only part I check the error ensure the content type is application/json other than that I dont touch the body in that part above.

Comment: Either there is no body, or something read it already. Are you using any other handlers or middleware? Can you provide a [mre]? What you have here (without `ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)` of course) does work as expected.

Comment: Sure let me provide more codes cause I minimize the codes to avoid too messy.

Comment: @jimB I have put my full working codes here https://pastebin.com/UFbmJTrP. Its the complete codes I remove everything else there.

Comment: The linked code is still using `ioutil.ReadAll` before attempting to decode (though the code is not valid because you are not passing an `io.Reader` to `newDecoder`)

Comment: @JimB sorry my mistake there. So that part is where I am stuck what is the correct method to settle on this been reading and googling too many things on this and keep trying them

Comment: @JimB here is the new version https://pastebin.com/6FL8ry2a I remove the ioutil.ReadAll. But it still giving me error EOF

Comment: And we're back to the same issue, we cannot tell what you are doing out of context, without a _complete_ example. The above code works, and will decode a json body.

Comment: @JimB I found a solution ready and testing later I post as solution to help other and its a complete different codes. Here is the link https://pastebin.com/iAbeFrXF. What is your opinion on this ?Do you think it secure enough to this way ?

Comment: "Secure enough" for what exactly? `DisallowUnknownFields` may be useful, but is unrelated to your `EOF` error.

Comment: @JimB Secure I mean in terms of the json data which is posted to my golang rest api. I will do research on this DisallowUnknownFields

Answer (score 1):

Please try running the following

```
func insertUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  type User struct {        
    Uemail string `json:"uEmail"`
    Upass string `json:"uPass"`    
  }
  var u User
  if r.Method == "POST" {
    if r.Header.Get("Content-Type") != "" {
      value, _ := header.ParseValueAndParams(r.Header, "Content-Type")
      if value != "application/json" {
          msg := "Content-Type header is not application/json"
          json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(Errormessage{msg});
          return
      }
    }

    // CODE CHANGED HERE
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    defer r.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
        return
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &u)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
        return
    }
    // CHANGED TILL HERE

    var uEmail string = u.Uemail
    var uPass string = u.Upass
   
    fmt.Println("User Namess :", uEmail)
    fmt.Println("User Password :", uPass)

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
  }
}
```